# jQuery BlockUI combined with jQuery Tools Tooltip issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-tools, jquery-blockui

I'm trying to use both the BlockUI and jQuery Tools Tooltip plugins on the same page and calls to BlockUI are fubaring the tooltips. Once I call .block() on an element the tooltips are offset by X number of pixels to the left and top and the width/height of the tooltips are all messed up. Any one else using these two libraries together and run into the same issue?

```
$("#MyAccount").block({ message: "<h1>Saving...</h1>" });
```

These are the two plugins I'm speaking of:

http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#overview

http://flowplayer.org/tools/demos/tooltip/index.html

[image: Initial page load - everything OK]

[image: After call to .block() the tooltips are fubared]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

BlockUI just doesn't play nice with other frameworks or plugins. I decided to use the jquery tools overlay to replace it and it works just as well.